# How to create a link that redirects to a website where a part of the URL is written in a textfield before?

Tags: html

First I have to say that I'm totally new to html so please excuse me, if this question is dumb.

It should look like this:

[image: expected]

And it should work like this:

The user enters a code, e.g. 123456, and when clicking the link, a website should open, where the URL is for example screenleap.com/123456.

How could this be possible to do? I have tried to do it and this is what I got until now:

```
<input type="text" name="code">
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.screenleap.com/code" target="_blank">Konferenz</a>
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: you can with javascript, have you tried yet ?

Comment: no I didn't, the only thing why I want to do is because I'm working with joomla and the SP Page Builder module there you can easily input a self written html code whereever you want, I'm not sure how that works with javascript, sorry I'm a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use native Javascript to do that :

```
<input type="text" name="code" id="code">
<br><br>
<a href="javascript:" onclick="window.open('https://www.screenleap.com/' + document.getElementById('code').value)">Konferenz</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

On change of the input rewrite the link like so:

```
$('input[name="code"]').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var val = $(e.target).val();
    $('a').attr('href', "https://www.screenleap.com/" + val)
});
```